# Why is bayesian glm values negative?

Tags: bayesian, pymc3, bernoulli-probability

I have a very basic pymc3 GLM Bernoulli model and was wondering why the values are negative? I must be doing something wrong, but I wish to be able to make predictions with the model.

[image]

[image]

How would I go about making predictions if the values are negative? I am looking to give an `x` value, use the model, and get a probability. Can anyone please explain to me how to be able to do that.